# Matching multiple words conditionally

Tags: python, regex

I have a large text file consisting of lines similar to the ones below:

```
timestamp = foo bar baz
timestamp = foo bar
timestamp = foo
```

I was trying to write a regex that matches foo, but if both bar and baz are present, that it matches those as well.

```
r"= (.*) (.*)? (.*)?"
```

but it only matches the `foo bar baz` string, not the other two. How can I make the regex match the optionals?

Comment: Something like `= *(\S+)(?: *(\S+))?(?: *(\S+))?` will work for you. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IyRoBP/1).

Comment: The only small niggle is that it matches the = for the `foo bar` case - unsure why :)

Comment: @CaseyJones add a positive lookbehind (?<=\=\s)(\S+)(?:\s*(\S+))?(?: *(\S+))?

Comment: `if line.endwith('foo') ...` ???

Comment: @CaseyJones What is the problem with matching `=`? I understand you are only interested in captured substrings.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew correct, my mistake - I was only looking at the highlights, not the groups. It was fairly late and I should've been in bed then. I stand corrected :)

Comment: I posted [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58068395/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that you can likely get the desired output using some simple expression, such as:

```
(\w+\s*=\s*)|(\w+)
```

#### Test

```
import re


regex = r"(\w+\s*=\s*)|(\w+)"
string = """
timestamp = foo bar baz foo bar baz
timestamp = foo bar baz
timestamp = foo bar
timestamp = foo
"""

for groups in re.findall(regex, string):
    if groups[0] == '':
        print(groups[1])
    else:
        print("--- next timestamp ----")
```

#### Output

```
--- next timestamp ----
foo
bar
baz
foo
bar
baz
--- next timestamp ----
foo
bar
baz
--- next timestamp ----
foo
bar
--- next timestamp ----
foo
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/VCHR7L/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/VCHR7L/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this will suffice?

```
 (?<=\=\s)(\S+)\s?(\S+)? ?(\S+)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PO3sHi/1)

Explanation:

```
 (?<=\=\s)       # Positive lookbehind - capture = + space but don't match
 (\S+)           # Capture any non-whitespace character
 \s?             # Capture optional space
 (\S+)?          # Capture any non-whitespace character
  ?              # Capture optional space
 (\S+)?          # Capture any non-whitespace character
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
r'= *(\S+)(?: *(\S+))?(?: *(\S+))?'
```

Or, to match any horizontal whitespaces:

```
r'=[^\S\r\n]*(\S+)(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\S+))?(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\S+))?'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OmdfWG/1)

**Details**

- `=[^\S\r\n]*` - a `=` char and any 0 or more chars other than LF, CR and non-whitespace (that is, all whitespace other than line feeds and carriage returns), or just spaces if you use  `*`
- `(\S+)` - Group 1: any 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\S+))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2: any 1+ non-whitespace chars
- `(?:[^\S\r\n]*(\S+))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `(\S+)` - Group 3: any 1+ non-whitespace chars

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/8uG27q):

```
import re
s = "timestamp = foo bar baz\ntimestamp = foo bar\ntimestamp = foo"
print( re.findall(r'= *(\S+)(?: *(\S+))?(?: *(\S+))?', s) )
# => [('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), ('foo', 'bar', ''), ('foo', '', '')]
```